# $\infty\pm\infty$ on a Riemann sphere

Tags: complex-analysis

Here I use "$\infty$" to represent the infinite point on a Riemann sphere. I read that

(1) $z\cdot\infty = \infty$ for any complex non-zero $z$.
(2) $\infty+\infty=\infty$.
(3) $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate.

(1) makes sense to me. I would expect that (2) and (3) are indeterminate. Although if  (2) is Inf, I expect that would mean that (3) is also Inf due to (1) and (2). If (1), (2), and (3) are correct as written above, why does it work that way?

----EDIT----

I take back (3) above, since I can't find a source that says that.

Howecer, (1) and (2) can be found in Mathematical Analysis, 2nd edition, by Tom M. Apostol. He includes it in his section on the extended complex plane. One response to my initial question and Wikipedia said $\infty+\infty$ is undefined. Does that mean not all mathematicians agree on this?

Comment: Where did you read this? On the Riemann sphere, I don't think (2) and (3) make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, $\infty \pm \infty$ are both undefined.

Comment: I recall reading it in a text book I left at work. I will check the book when I get to work tomorrow. Although I see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere says Inf +- Inf are both undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions $z\pm\infty$, $z\cdot \infty$ $(z\in{\mathbb C})$, $\infty\cdot\infty$, and $\infty\pm\infty$ are  **undefined** in the framework of field axioms for ${\mathbb C}$.

Since for $z\in{\mathbb C}$ (resp. $\in{\mathbb C}^*$) one has $z+ w_n\to\infty$  and $z\cdot w_n\to\infty$ as $w_n\to\infty$ ($n\to\infty$), it makes sense to define "a posteriori" $z+\infty:=\infty$ for all $z\in{\mathbb C}$ and $z\cdot\infty:=\infty$ when $z\ne0$. In this way the functions $$\phi_z: \bar{\mathbb C}\to\bar {\mathbb C}, \quad w\mapsto w+z\ ,\qquad\psi_z: \bar{\mathbb C}\to\bar {\mathbb C}, \quad w\mapsto z\cdot w\ ,$$
where $z\in{\mathbb C}$ (resp. $\in{\mathbb C}^*$) is *fixed*, are continuous on all of $\bar{\mathbb C}$.

In a **real** environment (e.g., in measure theory), it makes sense to enlarge ${\mathbb R}$ by  the "ideal point" $+\infty$. As $x_n\to\infty$ and $y_n\to\infty$ imply $x_n+y_n\to\infty$ the convention $x+\infty:=\infty$, $\infty+\infty:=\infty$ makes addition continuous at $(\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Woh! *prima vista* ... "at first sight".   According to the OED, in English this term is used only in music, also called "sight reading".

Comment: @Christian Blatter, It makes sense to me to say<br> $z\cdot\infty = \infty$ for any complex non-zero $z$.<br> and   the book Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol says this as well. Your second sentence agrees with this, but your first sentence says it is one of the things that are undefined. Please clarify.

Comment: @Ted Ersek: See my edit. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, I was thinking about this again. In Mathematical Analysis, 2nd Ed., section 1.33 Thomas M. Apostol says Inf+Inf=Inf when Inf is the Point at infinity on the extended complex plane. Can Apostol get away with this because he is not working in the framework of field axioms, or do you maintain that Apostol is wrong on this point?

Answer (score 3):

To say that $\infty-\infty$ is "indeterminate" means that if for every point $c$ in the Riemann sphere, there exist functions $f$ and $g$ and a point $a$ such that
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to a} f(z) & =\infty, \\[6pt]
\lim_{z\to a} g(z) & = \infty, \\[6pt]
\lim_{z\to a} f(z)-g(z) & = c.
\end{align}
You can choose point $a$ can be chosen to be anything you like and make trivial modifications in $f$ and $g$ so that this all works for that value of $a$.

When working with **real** numbers rather than on the Riemann sphere, this does not work for $\infty+\infty$ nor for $c\cdot\infty$.  If $f(z)\to\infty$ and $g(z)\to\infty$ then $f(z)+g(z)\to\infty$.  You cannot choose $f$ and $g$ both approaching $\infty$ in such a way that $f(z)+g(z)$ approaches $19$, the way you can with $f(z)-g(z)$.  However, with the Riemann sphere, as some have noted in comments below, similar things happen.

Comment: $\infty+\infty$ is just as bad as $\infty-\infty$ because the question concerns the Riemann sphere, where $\infty$ is the limit of, for example, the sequence $-1,-2,-3,\dots$ of negative integers.

Comment: Or of $n \cdot e^{in}$. $z \to \infty \iff \lvert z\rvert \to +\infty$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass : You have a point!  I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, I like the precise definition of Indeterminate. All other explanations I have read are hand wavy.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, although you should use "undefined" rather than "indeterminate" -- indeterminate is used *not* when you are doing arithmetic, but rather when you are trying to do other things, such as using *limit forms* to quickly compute limits.

The arithmetic of the Riemann sphere is the continuous extension of the arithmetic on the plane; if we did not remember that $\infty + \infty$ is undefined, we could use the previous fact to determine that ourselves, since we would have

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x + x = \infty + \infty = \lim_{x \to \infty} x + (-1) x $$

If we were working with the extended real numbers rather than the projective complex numbers, we would use two points at infinity $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. It is true that, in the extended real numbers, $(+\infty) + (+\infty) = +\infty$ but $(+\infty) - (+\infty)$ is undefined.

Unfortunately, people often use the same symbol for the projective infinity and the positive extended real infinity, which sometimes leads to confusion: the first equation in the previous paragraph would be written as $\infty + \infty = \infty$

Comment: I like the explanation of "undefined" vs "indeterminate". That point has puzzled me for a few years. I am an electrical engineer with a strong interest in math.

Answer (score -2):

This is not a mathematical issue, it's a memory trick or something when you want to find limits for instance.

Comment: I disagree.  See my posted answer.

Comment: Well, I disagree with your disagreement. But I won't bother fighting, I don't really care. In two words, as your answer shows, defining operations with $\infty$ is not a real thing, it's not like you are extending the complex operations or anything. It doesn't mean anything, it's just a way to remember how limits work.

Comment: The arithmetic of the Riemann sphere *is* an extension of the arithmetic of complex plane.... (specifically, it is identical with the continuous extension from the plane to the sphere of all of the arithmetic operators)